# How to edit multiple files in different directories in linux?

Tags: shell

I have several directories in linux where each directory has the same VCF file name and same initial few lines. Past those identical informative lines lies the data that I need. I want to essentially write a command line code that goes to each of these directories, edits the files so that the informative lines are removed and I am only left with the data.

When I tried this with a file by itself, I use the following code

```
find . -type f -name "File.vcf" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        awk 'substr($0,1,3)=="chr"' $file > "$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f2)"_cleaned.vcf
    done
```

This works and only gives me lines that start with chr which is what I want. Now I tried to step this up and with one command, I wanted to hit 7 birds with 1 stone and wrote the following code:

```
for i in "directory"; do
    cd /user/xxxxxxxx/$i |
        find . -type f -name "File.vcf" -print0 |
        while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
            awk 'substr($0,1,3)=="chr"' $file > "$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f2)"_cleaned.vcf
        done
    done
```

When I run this, the files are completely emptied out and I don't understand why. I am still trying to grasp linux and command line functions, but if anyone has tips, I would be grateful.

Comment: `cd ... | find` is not really doing what you want.  The `find` still runs in the current directory.  Perhaps you want: `cd ... ; find ...`  Make sure you either `pushd/popd` or run in a sub-shell to get back to the original directory.

Comment: But you probably don't need (or want) to `cd` anyway.  Just do `find $i` instead of `find .`

Comment: But....why the loop at all?  `find` can do the directory walk for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about the names, locations, and contents of the files you are targeting, it's hard to debug your specific problem. But I would refactor to

```
find directories -type f -name "File.vcf" \
    -exec 'for file; do
        grep "^chr" "$file" >"${file%.vcf}_cleaned.vcf"
    done' "$0" {} +
```

which should be more robust, more portable, and somewhat more efficient (though I had to guess about the positions of underscores in the names of the found files; perhaps I guessed wrong).

Like William Pursell comments, `cd | find` is not useful or correct. Pass the list of directories you want to search to `find` directly; it accepts a list of directories to traverse before the predicates.

The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${file%.vcf}` produces the value of the variable `$file` with any suffix `.vcf` trimmed off. The suffix expression can be a pattern, but if you require the text between two underscores, you need two parameter expansions (one to remove a prefix with `${file#*_}` and another to remove a suffix `${file%_*}`).